# AvalonEdit - Searching Completion Data

Tags: avalonedit

I've wired up the CompletionData no problem, inserting etc into the Avalon Edit control.

The challenge is the searching algorithm.

In the example below, I want ***new-obj*** to "match" ***New-Object**** in the list and not do a partial find on ***New-DataObject***.

Is there a flag I can set? Or do I need to override the search and implement my own?

Thank you

Doug

http://dougfinke.com/Stackoverflow/avalonedit.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this behavior is currently not customizable. It's hard-coded in the private method `CompletionList.GetMatchQuality`.

That said, I cannot reproduce your problem. The AvalonEdit matching logic doesn't work like your screenshot seems to suggest.
AvalonEdit supports 8 types of matches (with the higher ones having priority over the others):

```
        //      8 = full match case sensitive
        //      7 = full match
        //      6 = match start case sensitive
        //      5 = match start
        //      4 = match CamelCase when length of query is 1 or 2 characters
        //      3 = match substring case sensitive
        //      2 = match substring
        //      1 = match CamelCase
```

"new-obj" is a type 5 match for "New-Object", and no match at all for "New-DataObject".

The completion window is displayed suspiciously far to the right of the word start. I think only "obj" is in your completion segment. You'll have to check your code that finds the word start and sets `CompletionWindow.StartOffset`, I suspect it is considering the dash to be a word border.

Comment: Is there any chance you could make this customizable please? I'd like to implement [this](https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/issues/3) in my project, I have the matching function but there's no way to plug that in easily... :-\